# Web Api with & causing an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, .net-4.5

I'm working on a web api call that includes parameters with '&'.

I've tried uriEncodingComponent to get the following thinking it was going to fix the issue but I am still running into the same problem. The url I'm trying to reach is here below.

```
http://localhost:123/api/Apples/GetApples/Red%20%26%20Green/20
```

I have also tried changing the HTTPRuntime in my application, without any success, to the following:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" />
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *WebAPIConfig* had constraints that was not including *&*. Included modified my regex expression to accept the character.